# Why isn't my delegate object responding to method calls?

Tags: ios, objective-c, delegation

I ultimately want to write an iOS app incorporating ALAssetsLibrary, but as a first step toward understanding delegation, I'm trying to pass a simple message between two view controllers. For some reason, I can't seem to get the message to pass. In particular, the delegate object (derpy) doesn't appear to exist (`if(self.derpy)` returns `NO`)).

I asked the same question on the Apple forums and was told that I should be using segues and setting properties / calling methods using self.child instead, but that seems strange. If I were to pass messages using the parent / child properties, would I still be able to create my views in Interface Builder? Once I have my two views set up, say inside a UINavigationController, I'm not sure how to actually "wire them up" so I can pass messages between them. Sorry if the question is overly broad.

Here's the controller I'm declaring the protocol in (called PickerViewController):

Interface:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <AssetsLibrary/AssetsLibrary.h>

@protocol DerpDelegate <NSObject>
@required
- (void) test;
@end

@interface PickerViewController : UIViewController

@property (nonatomic, assign) id<DerpDelegate> derpy;

@end
```

Implementation:

```
   #import "PickerViewController.h"

    @interface PickerViewController ()   
    @end

    @implementation PickerViewController

    - (void)viewDidLoad
   {
        [super viewDidLoad];      
        if (self.derpy) {         // If the delegate object exists
            [self.derpy test];    // send it this message 
        } else {
            NSLog(@"Still not working.");     // This always returns (i.e., self.derpy doesn't exist)
        }
    }
```

Delegate controller (MainViewController) interface:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "PickerViewController.h"

@interface MainViewController : UIViewController <DerpDelegate> // public promise to implement delegate methods
@property (strong, nonatomic) PickerViewController *picker;

- (void) test;

@end
```

And lastly, the delegate controller (MainViewController) implementation:

```
#import "MainViewController.h"
#import "PickerViewController.h"

@interface MainViewController ()
@end

@implementation MainViewController

// Here's that method I promised I'd implement

- (void) test{ 
    NSLog(@"Test worked.");     // This never gets called
}

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.picker.derpy = self;

//lazy instantiation
- (PickerViewController *) picker{
if(!_picker) _picker = [[PickerViewController alloc]init];
return _picker;
}
```

EDIT: Many thanks to rydgaze for pointing me in the right direction with `self.picker.derpy = self`, but for some reason, things still aren't working properly. Importantly, once that property has been set, `if(self.picker.derpy)` returns `YES` from MainViewController. But `if(self.derpy)` is still returning `NO` when called from inside the PickerViewController's `viewDidLoad`. How can the property exist and not exist at the same time?

Comment: For some reason my angle brackets aren't appearing. Do I need to escape them somehow?

Comment: just use the code format button with your code selected. and why all this free lines?

Comment: (The code format button is the `{}` button above the text entry screen.  Highlight your code and press that button.)

Comment: Thanks. Sorry about the free lines, Apple forums auto-add them, forgot to scrub before I pasted in here.

Comment: Where do you actually instanciate `MainViewController` and where do you call its method `test`?

Comment: MainViewController is set in Interface Builder — it's the main view controller inside a UINavigationController. The method `test` gets called from PickerViewController's `-viewDidLoad`.

Comment: How and where do you create the instance of PickerViewController?

Comment: Apologies, was missing from MainViewController. The instance of PickerViewController get's alloc'd/init'd in its getter, which gets called when I set its property in `viewDidLoad`.

Comment: When and how are you getting the PickerViewController on screen? You're probably creating a second instance with your alloc init in the  getter method, and setting the delegate on that instance, rather than the one you get on screen.

Comment: I'm certain you're right - the views are in Interface Builder, inside a UINavigationController. Is there an easier way to pass messages between them than delegation?

Comment: No, you should still use delegation, but you should set the delegate in prepareForSegue. The segue.destinationViewController will be the instance of PickerViewController that's put on screen -- you should set the delegate there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to be sure that you're setting the delegate on the instance of the view controller that you put on screen. If you're using a navigation controller and segues to go between MainViewController and PickerViewController, then you should set the delegate in prepareForSegue:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    self.picker = (PickerViewController *)segue.destinationViewController;
    self.picker.derpy = self;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to populate the delegate first.

Basically, your MainViewController shoudl at somepoint do a

`picker.derpy = self;`

Then when the delegate fires in PickerViewController, the callback will happen.

Edit:
A good practice is to do something like in PickerViewController

```
@property (nonatomic, assign) id<DerpDelegate > derpy;
```

and in your MainViewController indicate that you will implement the delegate

```
@interface MainViewController : UIViewController<DerpDelegate>
```

Eventually in your implementation of MainViewController

You will have something like

```
picker = [[PickerViewController alloc]init];
picker.derpy = self;
[picker doYourThing];
```

Once picker is all done, it may want to return results using the delegate.

Comment: This is great, but for some reason the message still isn't being passed. Critically, if(self.picker.derpy) returns YES inside MainViewController, but if(self.derpy) returns NO inside PickerViewController. Do you have any idea why that would be?

Comment: I think it will be helpful to understand what exactly delegation is doing. Delegate is essentially pointer to an object to send a message (a.k.a invoke a function). So unless the object (the delegate) is populated, you cannot call a function on that.

Take a look at this link: http://alexefish.com/post/15966868557/understanding-and-creating-delegates-in-objective-c